# MySQL 5.7 to Maria DB 10.2 Max function 10X Slower

Tags: mysql, mariadb, max

MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.2 Max function 10X Slower

I have two identical servers same hardware one is running MySQL 5.7 and the other
upgraded to Maria DB 10.2 The query on the MySQL 5.7 server takes 84 ms and the same query
on MariaDB 10.2 takes 9.834 seconds. I don't understand why the explain output on the MySQL 5.7 server does not show any possible keys. I also don't understand why the MAX function is 10 times slower on MariaDB.  If I remove the MAX function on the Maria DB server that query runs in 81ms. I also can change the query to use DISTINCT and then wrap that in a select and do the MAX on the outside query.

Table Statistics:

Tables are identical on each server.

- Rows 11,127,819
- ENGINE=InnoDB
- CHARSET=utf8
- ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT

Among other indexes, there are the following indexes

- KEY `year` (`year`)
- KEY `e0212` (`e0212`),
- KEY `rada_YD` (`year`,`e0212`),

---

MYSQL 5.7 Server

Query: `SELECT MAX(year) AS Year FROM t WHERE e0212 = '999999';`

Execution time:  84 ms

EXPLAIN OUTPUT:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Select tables optimized away |

---

MariaDB 10.2 Server

Query: `SELECT MAX(year) AS Year FROM t WHERE e0212 = '999999';`

Execution time 9.834 s

EXPLAIN OUTPUT:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | t | ref | e0212 | e0212 | 20 | const | 5498670 | Using index condition |

Refactored query:
`SELECT MAX(a.year) FROM ( SELECT  DISTINCT(year) AS Year FROM t WHERE e0212 = '999999' ) as a;`

Execution time 81ms

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Adding (complete) output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE t1` from both servers ight help, because currently we can only assume that there are no indexes defines on the 5.7 server.

Comment: After looking more into the tables are NOT identical. The table on the MariaDB had an Id (int) Column added and set as the primary key with auto increment also has a unique key of (`year`,`e0212`,`submission`,`e0001`,`e0782`,`e0975`,`e0934`,`e0017`)  MySQL 5.7 does NOT have this Id column and has a primary key of (`year`,`e0212`,`submission`,`e0001`,`e0782`,`e0975`,`e0934`,`e0017`) This adds a new question as to why this would even matter. I removed the Id Key off the MariaDB table and set the primary key to what the MySQL had and its back to sub second query.

Answer (score 0):

**Caching**

10x smells like simply a caching issue.  The faster machine had all the blocks it needed already cached in RAM; the slower one needed to do the query.

Or, the data needed was smaller than the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Again, this is a caching issue.

Run the query twice on each machine.

**Better index**

Both machines will run faster with `INDEX(e0212, year)` *in that order*.  And, if you add that index, Drop your current `INDEX(e0212)` since it gets in the way of picking the optimal index.

The suggested refactoring is unlikely to help.

**Further debugging**

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` from each machine.

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  The lack of one probably does not impact *this* query.